# Select the employee who earned more

Tags: mysql

[MySQL] I want to select the employee who earned more, the problem is that I am using two tables.

Finally I have no idea how to do it.

I built a query that can count the number of services and sort by most, but the query is flawed as there services with higher values​​.

here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_servico` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_funcionario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servicos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Título do serviço',
  `descri` mediumtext COMMENT 'uma pequena descrição do serviço',
  `valor` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'valor bruto do serviço',
  `comissao` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'comissão por funcionario',
  `data` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Comment: Did you mean the employee that earned the most?

Comment: Post the query that isn't working and maybe someone will explain why. People don't like to answer one-off questions or do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all employees, join their "services", then group by employee ID, sum their income and select the first one.

```
SELECT E.id, SUM(S.amount) AS income
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN service S ON S.employee_id = E.id
GROUP BY E.id
ORDER BY income DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I saw your comment after replying... What can I say, that seemed simple so I scribbled a query.

Comment: I don't know why I was down voted, I hope it's not because I answered a bad question...

Comment: Is that really necessary? I am giving him a draft of query because he doesn't know where to start. I don't think I should be down voted...

Comment: Probably not necessary. I just felt like it.

Comment: this query does not return anything

Comment: I see SO as a kind of canon of knowledge. Endlessly filling it up with answers to basic questions which the questioners have made no apparent attempt to solve for themselves diminishes it in my view.

Comment: Try to update your query to use what I provided in my answer. Your SELECT and GROUP BY are wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry poster now has a query that doesn't work. They just did not post it with the initial question.

Comment: They did try to write a query.